# Existence of a Non-Linear Function Satisfying Certain Conditions

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^m}$ and $N: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^m}$ be two mappings satisfying:

$$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-N(h)}{h}=\vec 0.$$

If $f'(a)$ exists and is non-zero, is it possible $N$ to be non-linear? If so, please provide examples of $f$ and $N$, and specify $a$.

Aside: It's possible for $N$ to be linear, in which case $N$ is unique and is the differential $N(h)=hf'(a)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is: you can just add $g(h) h$ to $f'(a) h$, where $g(h) \to 0$ as $h \to 0$. An obvious example is $ \lvert h \rvert^{1+\alpha} b $, where $\alpha>0$ and $b$ is some constant of the right sort.

Comment: Thank you Chappers. Yes, I agree this is rather obvious. I assume you are setting $hg(h)$ to $ h^{1+\alpha} b $, where $\alpha>0$. Then $g(h)=h^{\alpha} b$, which approaches zero for any $b$ - isn't that right? So any constant will do - we do not have to restrict ourselves to "the right sort", correct?

Comment: @TSJ I mean that when you're in $\mathbb{R}^m$, derivatives are more complicated than just numbers, so you have to be careful about what type of object (linear map/matrix, vector, and so on) you're actually dealing with.